# image position and size

Tags: actionscript-3

First of all - I'm new to Flash..

I'm trying to load an external image as a background and the url is loaded with flashvars

```
var flashvars = LoaderInfo(this.loaderInfo).parameters;
if(flashvars.bg){
 var imageLoader = new Loader();
 var image = new URLRequest(flashvars.bg);
 imageLoader.load(image);
 addChild(imageLoader);
 imageLoader.x = 0;
 imageLoader.y = 0;
}
```

When the swf is compiled the image is not posisioned at 0,0 and it has been scaled down.. it has not the original dimensions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both positioning and scale should be correct, assuming that `this` is the main MovieClip instance (root).  My guess is you need to set `stage.scaleMode=StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;` and `stage.align=StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;`.

Comment: another thing.. how do you trace the properties in the object? for(var key in stage){
 trace(stage[key]);
}

Comment: No idea why they are not set as default - you'd have to ask Adobe, I suppose ;) `for (var key:String in ...)` only works on dynamic objects. Since Stage is a class, you'd have to explicitly trace the properties or use describeType() to get accessor and variable names.